# Why if for all x, p(x) and for all x not p(x) is not a contradiction?

Tags: predicate-logic, first-order-logic

$\forall x: p(x) \equiv1$ and $\forall x: \neg p(x) \equiv 1$ is not a contradiction?

I have this doubt after a logic contest, and I cant see why. My thoughs was that this is not a contradiction because maybe the TRUE set of these two proposition may be the empty set, but Im not sure if this is the right answer.

I will appreciatte any coment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*I think that there is a "terminological" issue here ...*

In "modern practice", we say that :

> a formula $\phi$ is a *contradiction*, or *inconsistent*, if it is *unsatisfiable*.

This definition can be easily applied to a set of formulae.

In this sense, the two formulae $\forall x p(x)$ and $\forall x \lnot p(x)$ form an *unsatisfiable* set of formulae (in the "usual" semantics that does not admit empty universes).

But there is an "older" meaning of *contradictory* : see [The Traditional Square of Opposition](http://plato.stanford.edu/entries/square/) :

> Two propositions are *contradictory* iff they cannot both be true and they cannot both be false.
>
> Two propositions are *contraries* iff they cannot both be true but can both be false.

According to these definitions, the two sentences are *contraries*, because they can be both *false*.

Answer (score 2):

The answer may depend on the universe of discourse. If $x$ is a variable for unicorns, then "All unicorns have blue eyes" and "all unicorns have non-blue eyes" are both true. However, we paractically *always* assume a nonempty universe of discourse (and some rules of natural deduction rely on that). In that case, from $\forall x p(x)\equiv 1$ we infer $p(a)\equiv 1$, from $\forall x \neg p(x)\equiv 1$ we infer $\neg p(a)\equiv 1$, and these two *are* in contradiction.

Comment: I think this could be the explanation if we had a usual equals sign. But what does the "triple equals sign" mean here? That the polynomial p is identically equal to one? In that case, we are referring to some polynomial (or other function) that exists in some universe, otherwise the the statement is not true or false but simply meaningless, right?

Answer (score 0):

Well I suppose, in [First-order logic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First-order_logic) one could consider an empty universe (or domain of discourse). In this case, any statement over an $\forall$ quantifier is true. So you could say that there exists a universe such that both statements are true and thus they are no contradictions.

This, however, relies very strongly on which definition one uses since mostly universes are assumed to be non-empty...